# JSON EXTRACT SUM returning 0 instead of correct value

Tags: mysql, json, database, group-by, sum

I'm trying to sum the contents of a json array in a mysql database, below is the JSON format and the query I'm running. Is there something wrong with it?

// Options JSON Format:

```
[
    {
        "optionId": 1,
        "optionName": "With Meat",
        "optionPrice": 2000
    },
    {
        "optionId": 2,
        "optionName": "With Veggies",
        "optionPrice": 0
    }
]
```

// Query:

```
SELECT id, SUM(options->'$[*].optionPrice') FROM table_order_items GROUP BY id;
```

The result is 0, when it should be 2000

While this query:

```
SELECT id, options->'$[*].optionPrice' FROM table_order_items;
```

correctly returns `[2000,0]`

Comment: `options->'$[*].optionPrice'` is JSON array. SUM() over it is obviously zero. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b272b83c3b1bd7e19913c5770576306 You must parse it to separate values (use JSON_TABLE) then SUM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the function [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to extract the prices:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       SUM(j.price) AS total 
FROM table_order_items t 
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
       t.options,
       '$[*]' COLUMNS(price INT PATH '$.optionPrice')
     ) j
GROUP BY t.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c26f259f83314c60e82ecb3e8617a632).